# php - good 'date' class for dealing with weekdays?

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a php class or library that helps deal with dates (meaning weekdays)? For example, I could use it to say "give me the timestamp for next Tuesday at 9:00" or "is this timestamp between next Tuesday and next Thursday".

I just have a part of my application that I need to make sure I'm not scheduling things at certain times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the built-in [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class, but you don't even need it for this:

```
//this gives results in the default timezone
//timestamp for next Tuesday at 9:00
strtotime("next tuesday 09:00");
//is this timestamp between next Tuesday and next Thursday
$ts >= strtotime("next tuesday") && $ts < strtotime("next friday")
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use strtotime()?

http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 2):

If you must use a class [Zend_Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html) is quite powerful. It comes with the Zend framework but is pretty standalone as far as I know. No obligation to implement MVC and all the other Zend stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) explain how to do this with `date`.